# Reset radio button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm have multiple radio button. After check or select radio button value randomly, i need to reset radio button to default checked or selected value on button click. My HTML code is below.

#### jQuery

```
function ResetRdo() {
    // Code to reset ?
}
```

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="a" checked="checked" />
            A
            <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="b" />
            B
            <input type="radio" name="rdo1" value="c" />
            C
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="1" />
            1
            <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="2" checked="checked" />
            2
            <input type="radio" name="rdo2" value="3" />
            3
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="1a" />
            1a
            <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="2b"  />
            2b
            <input type="radio" name="rdo3" value="3c" checked="checked" />
            3c
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="ResetRdo()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: checking all radio button value means

Comment: it means im selecting radio button. @ PSR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', function () {
    return this.getAttribute('checked') == 'checked';
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DNUdv/

Answer (score 2):

This might help.

```
$("input:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a unique id for each radio button like:

```
<input type="radio" name="rdo1" id="rdo1_a" value="a" checked="checked" />
```

Now in the function:

```
function ResetRdo() {
    $("#rdo1_a").attr('checked') == 'checked';
}
```

Use the same case for each set.

Comment: May be you have to use a class instead of Id, Not a good idea to use same id for all.

Comment: @ssilas777 I said a unique id for each radio button. The code snippet is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can give id for check boxes then do

```
  function reset(){ 
   $("#id").attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
```